# What is the purpose of the -t (--truncate) option of ddrescue?

Tags: terminal, command, ddrescue

When specifying an output file without specifying a logfile, the output file will be truncated anyway.

How exactly is using `ddrescue -t /dev/devicename outfile` functionally different from ordinarily specifying an output file?

The only way `ddrescue -t` (or `ddrescue --truncate`) is different is that when trying to specify a logfile, ddrescue responsds with:

```
ddrescue: Outfile truncation and logfile input are incompatible.
```

Comment: From the [ddrescue online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Introduction): "Ddrescue does not write zeros to the output when it finds bad sectors in the input, and does not truncate the output file if not asked to. So, every time you run it on the same output file, it tries to fill in the gaps without wiping out the data already rescued." So how did you arrive at the conclusion in the first sentence?

Comment: @Olorin Thanks. I arrived at that conclusion because I tested it. Both ways clobber the file.

Comment: @Olorin But it wipes out the data already rescued if I do not specify a logfile, therefore no difference, as far as I can think of.

Comment: What test did you use? How did you know it wiped out data already rescued?

Comment: @Olorin It did only wipe test data. I tested it by running both commands for 5 seconds, and the file size was approximately the same in both case. So it must have been rewritten.